# Net Automatic Serialization vs Custom Serialization Difference

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

In C#, what is the difference between Automatic serialization and Customer Serialization? Also what is Reflection? I know this stuff is not simple, if someone can explain in lay man's term, that would be great. I am beginner in all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word: *performance.*

Automatic serialization relies on Reflection.  While this provides a very good programmer experience, because one serializer works for many types, you take a performance hit because you're using Reflection to do all the heavy lifting.

Because custom serializers can be tailored specifically to the types being serialized, you can write them without using reflection and get significant performance gains.  The tradeoff, of course, is that custom serializers require significantly more effort to write.

You can control the way automatic serialization works by using [serialization attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes), so tweaking serialization behavior is not really a compelling reason to write a custom serializer.

Custom serializers can also be used to manage versioning between objects; see [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization).